# Get all non repeated "pair" combination using checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I need to get all non repeated possible combinations using as input marked checkboxes. This is the code I'm working on:

```
$('#triggerEv').on('click', function () {
    var firstTblItems = $("#firstTbl").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
        secondTblItems = $("#secondTbl").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        itemsArr = [],
        currPair;

  for (i; i < firstTblItems.length; i++) {
    for (j; j < secondTblItems.length; j++) {
      currPair = firstTblItems.eq(i).val() + '_' + secondTblItems.eq(j).val();
      if (itemsArr.indexOf(currPair) === -1) {
        itemsArr.push(currPair);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(itemsArr);
});
```

In this case, if you check all of them, right output should be:

```
itemsArr = [
        "1_1",
        "1_2",
        "1_3",
        "1_4",
        "2_1",
        "2_2",
        "2_3",
        "2_4",
];
```

And taking text should be get something like this:

```
Item 1 - Item 1
Item 1 - Item 2
Item 1 - Item 3
Item 1 - Item 4
Item 2 - Item 1
Item 2 - Item 2
Item 2 - Item 3
Item 2 - Item 4
```

But I'm getting this:

```
itemsArr = ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4"];
```

Which is wrong, can I get some help with my code? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/uxp8qfc0/4/) is a Fiddle for playing with.

Comment: shouldn't the right answer be `1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 1_4, 2_2, 2_3, 2_4, 3_3, 3_4, 4_4`? or did i get it wrong?

Comment: @neo perhaps I'm wrong, see my edit I have added more info, anyway from where did you get `3_3, 3_4, 4_4`?

Comment: isn't `1_2` and `2_1` a repeated pair?

Comment: @neo no, it has logic, see the text ouput is not the same `Item 1 - Item 2` and `Item 2 - Item 1` even keys are different

Comment: Ok what about `item 3 - item 3`?

Comment: and what is table 2 is point here, i thought you somehow want to map table 1 to table 2

Comment: @neo Perhaps, don't know what map will give me but solution provided in the answer do what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not re-initializing the `j` loop each time through. After the first outer loop, `j` is stuck at `secondTblItems.length` forever, so the inner loop never runs again.

Just correct the loop initialization, replacing:

```
for (i; i < firstTblItems.length; i++) {
  for (j; j < secondTblItems.length; j++) {
```

with:

```
for (i = 0; i < firstTblItems.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < secondTblItems.length; j++) {
```

```js
$('#triggerEv').on('click', function() {
  var firstTblItems = $("#firstTbl").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
    secondTblItems = $("#secondTbl").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
    i,
    j,
    itemsArr = [];

  for (i = 0; i < firstTblItems.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < secondTblItems.length; j++) {
      var currPair = firstTblItems.eq(i).val() + '_' + secondTblItems.eq(j).val();
      if (itemsArr.indexOf(currPair) === -1) {
        itemsArr.push(currPair);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(itemsArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First table</div>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="firstTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer[]" id="man-1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer[]" id="man-2" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer[]" id="man-5" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer[]" id="man-4" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>Second table</div>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="secondTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" id="branch-1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" id="branch-2" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" id="branch-5" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]" id="branch-4" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>Result table</div>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="resultTbl"></table>
<button id="triggerEv">Combine values</button>
```

Comment: Might help to point out code differences instead of having to scan line by line for them